# KeyListener problem

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, keylistener

In my apllication i am using a jpanel in which i want to add a key listener. I did it. But it doesnot work.

Is it because i am using a swingworker to update the contents of the panel every second.

Here is my code to update the panel

```
RenderedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) get()));
        Graphics graphics = remote.rdpanel.getGraphics();
        if (graphics != null) {
            Image readyImage = new ImageIcon(UtilityFunctions.convertRenderedImage(image)).getImage();
            graphics.drawImage(readyImage, 0, 0, remote.rdpanel.getWidth(), remote.rdpanel.getHeight(), null);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the `JPanel` have keyboard focus?

I suggest you use the `InputMap` and `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` or something similar. Excerpt from [How to Use Key Bindings](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html):

> The WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW input maps of all the enabled components in the focused window are searched. Because the order of searching the components is unpredictable

That has worked very robustly for me. Have a look at my other post for more information and actual code examples:

- [Keyboard input for a game in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702203/keyboard-input-for-a-game-in-java/2702391#2702391)

or this tutorial: [Swing: Understanding Input/Action Maps](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19402.html)

Related question:

- [JPanel not listening to key event when there is a child component with JButton on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793002/jpanel-not-listening-to-key-event-when-there-is-a-child-component-with-jbutton-on)