# Java Swing 2D Game - EventQueue stops firing after CardLayout switch

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, cardlayout

We want to add a menu to our 2D game.

So far, we had our game loop running on the main thread while the `EventQueue` from Swing was handling key inputs to our game. Now since we want to add the menu, we no longer can simply start the gameloop from our main method.

The problem: We don't know how to start the gameloop in such a way that the `EventQueue` keeps receiving the `KeyEvent`s.

Here's what we have in our menu:

```
startGameButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)Menu.this.getParent().getLayout();
            cl.show(Menu.this.getParent(), "Game");
        }
    });
```

So clicking the `startGameButton` removes the menu from the `JFrame` and shows the game itself, but the game is frozen, because we don't start the gameloop from our main thread anymore. We think that it's here, that we need to start the gameloop.

So we created a new `Thread` that will run our gameloop to prevent freezing our UI:

```
startGameButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)Menu.this.getParent().getLayout();
            cl.show(Menu.this.getParent(), "Game");

            Thread gameThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        game.update();
                        game.repaint();
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    }
                }
            });
            gameThread.start();
        }
    });
```

This works perfectly, the game shows up, and it's running... BUT: Our `KeyEvent`s are no longer firing. Somehow the `EventQueue` is not picking up keystrokes anymore and we don't know why.

Having the exact same code (creating the `Thread` and starting it) in the main method without using the `CardLayout` menu works perfectly fine, also getting `KeyEvent`s. So we think the problem is somewhere in using the `CardLayout` but we don't know what it is exactly.

Comment: Take a look here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793002/jpanel-not-listening-to-key-event-when-there-is-a-child-component-with-jbutton-o

Comment: @D-Klotz Thanks, I will try it out and let you know if that solution works for me.

Comment: @D-Klotz Sadly, using input maps doesn't solve my problem, still after hitting the `startGameButton` the `KeyListener` for the `JPanel` of the game is not firing its events.

Comment: Perhaps you need to post how you are implementing your input maps. Create a standalone code sample that shows the problem? Usually when I do that, I discover the problem...

Comment: The problem was neither the implementation of the input maps nor the KeyListener itself, it was simply a focus issue. Because hitting the `startGameButton` removed the focus from the `JPanel` of the game. It is resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to D-Klotz for the comment about the input maps problem. Even though it was not the correct solution for my problem, it caused me to notice someting:

When switching from the JFrame to another window and then back, the KeyListener was working fine again. So the only line of code missing in the `actionPerformed` method was:

```
game.requestFocus();
```

Works like a charm. Thanks for your help again.