# Card Layout will originally switch panels, by why won't it switch after the start of the program?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout

So I've encountered a weird type of error. I'm using a card layout to switch between a help panel and a user panel in a GUI. Upon originally starting the program the card layout works as expected and will switch whenever the user presses "H", but if you click any of the Buttons or type in the text fields you can no longer switch the card panel. I looked through oracle docs but found nothing. Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

```java
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    userPanel up = new userPanel();
    HelpPanel hp = new HelpPanel();
    private boolean showUserPanel = true;

    private Timer mainTimer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            up.setTipPercent();
        }
    });
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//Constructor
    public MainPanel(){
        setLayout(cl);
        add(up, "userPanel");
        add(hp, "HelpPanel");
        cl.show(this, "userPanel");
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        mainTimer.start();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//Key Listener Methods
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode == e.VK_H && showUserPanel == true){
            cl.show(this, "HelpPanel");
            mainTimer.stop();
            showUserPanel = false;
        }else if(keyCode == e.VK_H && showUserPanel == false){
            cl.show(this, "userPanel");
            showUserPanel = true;
            mainTimer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

This is the `userPanel` Class

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
public class userPanel extends JPanel{
    //Fields
    private JButton calc;
    private JRadioButton fiveP, tenP, fiftP, twenP;
    private ButtonGroup buttonGroup;
    private double tipAmount = 0.0;
    private JTextField tipArea;
    private JTextArea totalArea;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------         
//Constructor
    public userPanel(){
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        tipArea = new JTextField("Enter bill amount");
        totalArea = new JTextArea("");
        setupButtons();
        tipArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,40));
        totalArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,40));
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//Setup JComponents
    public void setupButtons(){
        calc = new JButton("Calculate the Tip");
        calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                calculateTheTip(tipAmount);
            }
        });
        buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

        fiveP = new JRadioButton("Five Percent");
        tenP = new JRadioButton("Ten Percent");
        fiftP = new JRadioButton("Fifteen Percent");
        twenP = new JRadioButton("Twenty Percent");

        buttonGroup.add(fiveP);
        buttonGroup.add(tenP);
        buttonGroup.add(fiftP);
        buttonGroup.add(twenP);

        add(fiveP);
        add(tenP);
        add(fiftP);
        add(twenP);

        add(tipArea);
        add(totalArea);

        add(calc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//Calculate the total and display it to the user
public void calculateTheTip(double total){
    String theTotal = tipArea.getText();
    //Take user input and make sure it is a number
    try{
        double billAmount = Double.parseDouble(theTotal);
        total = billAmount*total;
        double totalAmt = billAmount + billAmount*tipAmount;
        totalArea.setText("Tip: "+total+ " \nTotal: " + totalAmt);
    }catch(NumberFormatException E){
        totalArea.setText("Please Enter only the amount without a $ or text!");
    }
    return;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//Chose which tipPercent to use     
    public void setTipPercent(){
        if(fiveP.isSelected()){
            tipAmount = .05;
        }else if(tenP.isSelected()){
            tipAmount = .1;
        }else if(fiftP.isSelected()){
            tipAmount = .15;
        }else{
            tipAmount = .2;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `Help Panel` class

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class HelpPanel extends JPanel{
    public HelpPanel(){
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing a button, etc, takes the focus away from `MainPanel`. The `KeyEvent`s are being sent to the object that has focus instead of `MainPanel`.

I would suggest creating the `KeyListener` as a separate object and adding it to the other components.

Comment: What do you mean adding it to the other components?

Comment: @BobbyC.Robillard In `MainPanel`'s constructor you have `addKeyListener(this)`. That adds the `KeyListener` to your instance of `Main Panel`. You'll have to do this this for the other components like `button.addKeyListener(listener); [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702203/keyboard-input-for-a-game-in-java/2702391#2702391) might help.

Comment: Why would I add the keyListener to the button or other components? None of those are supposed to have the focus. I do not understand why you linked that thread, it doesn't seem to apply, or if it does could you please explain why?

Comment: When the user clicks on a button, that button gains focus. The button will retain focus until the either the user clicks on something else or your code programmatically transfer focus to another component. It sounds like you should review the [Focus Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) and [KeyListener Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: I believe I understand now, I'm reviewing Java Key_Binding documents. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your program cannot know if by clicking `H` you mean the card changing key press is pressed or if you are writing in a `JTextField`.

For your problem use Key Bindings, It's the best solution for this as it changes the focus to the component you want to to focus on. Read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) on this.

Comment: Yes I could do that, but that is not the goal. But if I understand correctly any time the user interacts with another component of the userPanel focus is transferred to that component?

Comment: @BobbyC.Robillard Ok I Edited my answer, turns out that Key bindings is possibly the best solution to your problem, since the object here is the focus on a particular  component , carefully read the docs , I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes I believe it is, I am currently reviewing the documents, thanks for your help!